# How can I get my JButtons to go into the same window as my image?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm trying to write a blackjack game and I want to have one window in which both the table image sits, and the hit/stay buttons sits. However, even when I try to add(@param) the hit/stay button objects to the frame, the buttons show up in separate windows as the table.

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class BlackjackTable extends JComponent{

  private static final int WIDTH = 1200;
  private static final int HEIGHT = 800;
  private Rectangle table;
  private JButton hitOrStay;

  public BlackjackTable(){
    table = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel lab = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("blackjackTableCanvas.jpg"));
    frame.setSize(1200,800);
    lab.setSize(1200,800);
    frame.add(lab);
    hitOrStay = new HitOrStayButton();
    frame.add(hitOrStay);
    frame.setTitle("Test Canvas");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.draw(table);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    BlackjackTable b = new BlackjackTable();

  }
}
```

My hit or stay button:

```
public class HitOrStayButton extends JButton{

JButton stayButton = new JButton("STAY");
JButton hitButton = new JButton("HIT");

public HitOrStayButton(){
  ActionListener pressChoice = new DecisionListener();
  hitButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);
  stayButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);
  JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
  testPanel.add(hitButton);
  testPanel.add(stayButton);
  JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
  testFrame.add(testPanel);
  testFrame.setSize(300, 150);

  testFrame.setVisible(true);
}

class DecisionListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){

      if(a.getSource() == hitButton){
        System.out.println("YOU CHOSE HIT!");
      }
      else if(a.getSource() == stayButton){
        System.out.println("YOU CHOSE STAY!");
      }

    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){
    HitOrStayButton h = new HitOrStayButton();
  }

}
```

how can I get the frame to have the image in it with the buttons in a panel at the bottom?

Comment: I don't see any need for `HitOrStayButton` to be creating a new window, not even sure I see a need for you to be extending from `JButton`.  `BlackjackTable` doesn't need to be creating it's own window either, these are unrequired side effects. You should create a window and place the other components onto

Comment: Start with a basic tutorial:  [add image](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/LoadimagetoImageIconandaddittoPanel.htm) . When this is successful add another `JPanel` to the `JFrame`. Add the two buttons to the 2nd `JPanel`

Comment: thanks! but now I only see the buttons but do not see a frame. Also, how can I preserve my object-oriented design (as in the button set itself be an object? I tried to keep it as one but in that case, it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public class HitOrStayButton extends JButton{
>
>  JButton stayButton = new JButton("STAY");
>  JButton hitButton = new JButton("HIT");
> ```

Would you expect a Car having two other cars inside?

First go your way through the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 1):

> in which both the table image sits, and the hit/stay buttons sits

You need to learn to use "layout managers" effectively. The default layout manager for the content pane of the frame is a `BorderLayout`. You can't just add multiple components to the same location. You need to specify different constraints (like `BorderLayout.CENTER` and `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`) when you add the components.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.